# What is the name of the "yield return" concept? IEnumerable, Iterator, Generator?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, terminology, yield

What exactly is the official name of the `yield return` concept?

```
public IEnumerable<T> Bar() {
    ...
    yield return foo;
    ...
}
```

I've heard(read) it being referred to as:

- Iterator
- IEnumerabe
- Generator
- <your choice>

Isn't an iterator just some "thing" that iterates over something? A `List<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`, so doesn't seem reasonable as well.

A lot of answers here on SO that talk about `yield return` use one of these two terms.

What about "generators"? Or does that only apply when you're "conjuring up values out of thin air", e.g. the Fibonacci Numbers where you don't need a data collection as a source?

Comment: Same, generator. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29#C.23

Comment: Generator for sure, although that's a Python term.

Comment: I'd say the term itself predates its usage in Python quite a bit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general concept in a non-language specific way, "generator" is probably the most common term. That's what I'd use if I were talking to someone who wasn't familiar with C#.

The method itself is an *iterator* in C# specification terminology. The implementation is an *iterator block*.

From section 10.14 of the C# 4 spec:

> A function member (§7.5) implemented using an *iterator block* (§8.2) is called an *iterator*.

That's the terminology I'd use when talking about C# specifically.

Comment: I do wonder though, why did they go with an already [established name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) for something different? (I can see that `yield` tremendously simplifies writing iterators)

Answer (score 3):

The principal it is useful for though is "Coroutine". See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

> Coroutines are computer program components that generalize subroutines
>   to allow multiple entry points for suspending and resuming execution
>   at certain locations. Coroutines are well-suited for implementing more
>   familiar program components such as cooperative tasks, iterators,
>   infinite lists and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

It's called an iterator, check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) page

> An iterator is a method, get accessor, or operator that performs a
>   custom iteration over an array or collection class by using the yield
>   keyword

Comment: Technically, it is sound, I guess, just sounds funny ;p