# Is it possible that a LINQ (to Object) query contains infinite loop?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a simple class:

```
public class RawBomItem
{
    private string material;
    private string item;
    private string component;
    private string quantity;
    private string b;
    private string spt;
...
}
```

and for every datamember there is a property.

And then I have a List containing the instances of this class

```
    private List<RawBomItem> rawBom;
```

The List contains more than 70000 items.

At this point I wanted to run a little complex LINQ query on this List.

```
List<string> endProducts = new List<string>(
    rawBom.Where(x1 => new List<string>(rawBom.Select(x2 => x2.Component)
                                              .Distinct())
                           .Contains(x1.Material) && (x1.B != "F"))
          .Select(x3 => x3.Material));
```

The query seems like it run into an infinite loop. (I've waited for some minutes before shut it down)

I will turn it into DB to work, I'm just interested in what can be the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one line?

Comment: Well, try reducing the list length to a few hundred to see if it still works...

Comment: It's quite unclear what this query does, but consider that it filters 70K items. For each one it processes 70K items up to twice each. So we are looking at about 5 to 10 **billion** iterations. That should take some time. In other words: O(N²) is not good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see how there should be an infinite loop, but your code is extremely inefficient.
For every item in `rawBom` you calculate the distinct set of the components and copy them into a new list. So, with 70,000 items in your list, you perform 70.000 ^ 2 = 4,900,000,000 iterations. Furthermore, for every item in your list, you are iterating the list of distinct components yet again. Depending on how many distinct components you have, you add the same number of iterations on top.

This can be improved:

```
var components = new HashSet<string>(rawBom.Select(x => x.Component).Distinct());
var endProducts = rawBom.Where(x => components.Contains(x.Material) &&
                                    x.B != "F")
                        .Select(x => x.Material)
                        .ToList();
```

1. We extract the creation of the list of distinct components from the main query, so we have to calculate it only once - and not 70.000 times.
2. We use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`. This changes the call to `Contains` from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

The end result is that you enumerate your list only twice, resulting in only 140,000 iterations. Now compare that to the original number of iterations.

Comment: I love the use of `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Definitely a +1 for recognizing that.

Comment: Doesn't `new Hashset()` perform its own `Distinct()`, obviating the need for doing it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a reach that it's an infinite loop. Unless your sequence is a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799572/what-is-the-name-of-the-yield-return-concept-ienumerable-iterator-generator), but you don't have that here.

What you have is code that is inefficient as all hell.

```
rawBom.Where( // this goes over the 70,000 item collection once
```

for each of those 70,000 you have:

```
new List<string>(rawBom.Select(x2 => x2.Component).Distinct()) // this goes over the 70,000 collection 3 times (first select, then distinct, then new list)
.Contains // another bunch of accesses depending on how many distinct items there were
.Select(x3 => x3.Material) // iterates over the resulting collection once
```

So it's going to be slow, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your query a little bit. I think this is what you want?

```
List<string> endProducts = rawBom
.Where(x1 => rawBom.Any(x2 => x2.Component == x1.Material) && x1.B != "2")
.Select(x1 => x1.Material).ToList();
```

This won't create any additional lists for every item in the rawBom, but will use it itself

Comment: It still iterates close to 5 billion times.

Comment: Sure, using HashSet is much better. I havent't seen your proposal when I wrote mine :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.Any(x2 => x2.Component == x1.Material)`?  The original is creating a list of Components and seeing if the list contains the Material, not if it contains a value that Material is a substring of.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<RawBomItem> list = new List<RawBomItem>();
var components = list.Select(x => x.component).Distinct();
var b = new Func<RawBomItem, bool>(x =>
  {
    return components.Contains(x.Material) && x.B != "F";
  });
var v = list.Where(x => b(x)).Select(x1 => x1.material).ToList();
```